# Can't customize the name of PDF file generated by 'html-pdf' npm module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, html-pdf

I am using html-pdf node module to generate a pdf and email via nodemailer. Everything is working file. Only One problem I am facing right now is that I can't set the name of my pdf file generated. I am attaching the code for generate pdf function.

```js
const generatePdf = (data, user, startDate, endDate, linkRes) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log("*&&&&& Here in generate Report", linkRes);
    const body = renderToString( <App meetingsData={data} userData={user} startDate={startDate} endDate={endDate} linkRes={linkRes} /> );
    const title = 'Therify Meeting Report';
    let returnObj = {};
    const phantomPath = require('witch')('phantomjs-prebuilt', 'phantomjs');
    const html = Html({body, title});
    console.log("*&&&&& path", phantomPath);

    
    const options = {
      format: 'A4',
      orientation: 'portrait',
      // phantomPath: `${phantomPath}`,
      header: {
        "height": "3mm",
      },
      footer: {
        "height": "5mm",
        "contents": {
          default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>',
        }
      },
    };
    
    pdf.create(html, options).toBuffer(function (err, file) {
      console.log('This is a file:', file);
      if(err) {
        returnObj.data = `Pdf Generation Failed`;
        returnObj.status = 500;
        res(returnObj);
      }else {
        buffer = file;
        returnObj.data = `Pdf Generated Successfully`;
        returnObj.status = 200;
        res(returnObj);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The name of the pdf file generated is set to 'attachment-1.pdf'. I want to change it. Here is a picture attached of the pdf generated.
[image: Generated PDF file]

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this

keep the below code inside the pdf.create function hope it will work

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;Abc.pdf");
```

Comment: Actually, I got it to work. The name of the pdf file was not set in Nodemailer. So Nodemailer was using a default value for the file name. I resolved the issue. Thanks, BTW.